# SSRS report, repeating same field as table

Tags: reporting-services

I have a 500 article no. in my database table.  I want to display them in SSRS report in form of grid.  I mean a table with 5 columns to be used.

I tried it in different ways, I could only display one column in one row.
Then next field is displayed in the first column of next row (so I have 500 rows, where I want to finish it in 100 rows, using 5 columns)

Kindly advise how to configure it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows form rdlc report repeat columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843202/windows-form-rdlc-report-repeat-columns); please note that this answer works at report level so you probably need a subreport (with multiple column) if you want a group header like in your image.

Answer (score 0):

This link shows the way to display data in multiple columns https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12331/Simple-way-to-show-multi-column-data-in-SSRS-Horizontally-or-Vertically.html