# windows form rdlc report repeat columns

Tags: winforms, rdlc

I want to create a rdlc report that will look similar to this so I could print many records to save spaces and papers. Lets say. . if I have 120 rows in my table and i want to display it 3 columns so each columns will have 40 records each instead of displaying them all the way vertically.

```
Column Header | Column Header | Column Header
---------------------------------------------
   value 1         value 7         value 13
   value 2         value 8         ...
   value 3         value 9         ...
   value 4         value 10        ...
   value 5         value 11        ...
   value 6         value 12        ...
```

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the question exactly? How to create an RDLC report? How to craete dynamically at run-time? How to change column titles at run-time? Please elaborate more ...

Comment: Sorry about that. I already updated my question. I hope you'll get what I mean now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `Columns` and `ColumnSpacing` properties of your report:

1. display `Property` window
2. click on `Report` (grey area outside your
   page)
3. find and set `Columns` property